# Javascript: remove digits with regex except digits matching a pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that contains a list of words.

Example:
thing1, list1, machine(10%), 12345 X 123, X 456g

Now all digits and special characters should be removed.
But NOT numbers that match the pattern 'X Blank followed by 3 digits'.

The result should look like this:
thing, list, machine, X 123, X 456g

Removing the numbers completely is quite easy:

`s = s.replace(/[0-9]/g, '');`

But how can I get the above result?
I would be happy about some hints.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use:

```js
let example = 'thing1, list1, machine(10%), 12345 X 123, X 456g';
let rx = /(X \d{3})|\s*\(?\d+%?\)?/g;

example = example.replace(rx, function (match, group1) {
    if (typeof(group1) == "undefined") {
        return "";
    } else {
        return group1;
    }
});
console.log(example);
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/zCByYh/1).